# how to enable/disable gpio-keys autorepeat in runtime

Tags: linux-kernel, keyboard-events, autorepeat

I am new here.
I am not a professional programmer. I am actually HW guy.
It just ended up that I had to deal with these things.
So my terms may not be correct or clear. Please understand.

This is about embedded device with Linux version 3.10.14.
My device has two buttons and I mapped them to gpio-keys or KEYBOARD_GPIO.

So it seems that setting the value of 'rep' in struct gpio_keys_platform_data will enable or disable the autorepeat function.
But can I enable or disable the autorepeat function from console?
or from user program?

And another question came to me just now.
Can I enable autorepeat for one key and disable it for the other?
Maybe assigning each key to two different gpio-keys device?

Thanks for reading.